# odoo 10 how to create Snippets Javascript option

Tags: odoo-10

I'm trying to Create Snippets in odoo 10 according to https://www.odoo.com/documentation/10.0/howtos/themes.html#create-snippets

I created the snippets and add the js option, the code from the example

```
(function() {
    'use strict';
    var website = odoo.website;
    website.odoo_website = {};

    website.snippet.options.snippet_testimonial_options = website.snippet.Option.extend({
        on_focus: function() {
            alert("On focus!");
        }
    })
})();
```

fails since odoo.website is not defined see

[image]

Please help

Answer (score 7, accepted):

here is the correct code for /theme_tst/static/src/js/tutorial_editor.js

```
odoo.define('snippet_testimonial_options', function(require) {

    'use strict';

    var options = require('web_editor.snippets.options');

    options.registry.snippet_testimonial_options = options.Class.extend({

        on_focus: function() {

            alert("On focus!")

        },

    });

});
```

Answer (score 1):

for odoo11: I need to change on_focus to onFocus (didn't try on odoo10)

```
odoo.define('snippet_testimonial_options', function(require) {
    'use strict';
    var options = require('web_editor.snippets.options');
    options.registry.snippet_testimonial_options = options.Class.extend({

        onFocus: function() {

            alert("On focus!")

        },

    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**sombatsombat** answer works for me. In odoo 12 `onFocus` is used. List of events are given on this [link](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/12.0/howtos/themes.html#javascript-options).

Also first argument `snippet_testimonial_options` is optional. we can simply ignore it.

```
odoo.define(function (require) {
    var options = require('web_editor.snippets.options');
    console.log(options);
    options.registry.snippet_testimonial_options = options.Class.extend({
        onFocus: function () {
            alert("On focus!")
        },
    });
});
```