# odoo_website variable not defined in odoo 10 while adding javascript in custom snippet

Tags: odoo, odoo-10

I was going through the odoo 10 theme tutorial for the following website
https://www.odoo.com/documentation/10.0/howtos/themes.html#javascript-options

I did exactly what the tutorial said but also I am getting error in following code:

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    var website = odoo.website;
    website.odoo_website = {};//    odoo_website veriable is undefined;

website.snippet.options.snippet_testimonial_options = website.snippet.option.extend({
    on_focus: function () {
        alert("On focus!");
    }
})
})();
```

Here is the screen shot of the console:
[image: error screen shot odoo 10 odoo_website]

Answer (score 1):

In case someone already arrives to this post looking for an answer. The solution for Odoo 11 (and Odoo 12 in my case) was suggested by [sombatsombat](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1825573/sombatsombat) here https://stackoverflow.com/a/49089701/9693357

Basicaly you should re-write your function in this way:

```
odoo.define('snippet_testimonial_options', function(require) {
    'use strict';
    var options = require('web_editor.snippets.options');
    options.registry.snippet_testimonial_options = options.Class.extend({

        onFocus: function() {

            alert("On focus!")

        },

    });
});
```

I don't know why in the Theme Tutorial is providing that other way which produces the error.

Comment: almost one year later, Nov 2019 and I found myself like yours. glad found your solution

Answer (score 0):

try

```
(function() {
    'use strict';
    var website = openerp.website;
    website.openerp_website = {};
})();
```

Comment: Wouldn't this be better with a small explanation along with the code?